# JabberIqAuth plugin not being called/used in Tigase

Tags: java, tigase

I'm trying to do a custom login plugin by extending overriding JabberIqAuth with my own plugin, because I want to send the user a custom message depending on the account status. However, after I've installed the plugin, I found out that it's not being called, and neither is the original JabberIqAuth when I check the tigase logs.

The only thing I've found after searching was that the JabberIqAuth isn't used, but rather, the tigase-custom-authenticator ( http://www.tigase.org/content/tigase-custom-auth-connector ) is actually used, and this would require me to change the server and recompile it, instead of using a plugin. Is there any way to get around that, and use the custom JabberIqAuth instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the JabberIqAuth is not being used in the registration, but rather the SaslAuth plugin.